# Laravel: pagination on search method not updating the url

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently working on a project where one page displays all items currently in the db, and I use laravel's pagination. This works perfectly fine. But the page also has a search functionality to search for specific items. This is where I encounter my problem.

At the moment the, after the search the first page is displayed fine, but when I press the buttons to go to any other page I get always the first page (the page refreshes but the url doesn't change and I get page 1 again). If I manually change the url to the href on the link it works but pressing the button doesn't change the url. page number is not appending.

Here is my controller

```
public function searchItems(Request $request)
  {
    if (!Auth::check() || !Auth::user()->is_admin()) return redirect('/login');

    $request->validate([

      'admin-query' => 'required|min:3',

    ]);

    $query = $request->input('admin-query');

    $items_aux = DB::select("SELECT id, ts_rank_cd(textsearch, query) AS rank FROM \"item\", to_tsquery('english','.$query') 
      AS query, to_tsvector(name || ' ' || description) AS textsearch WHERE query @@ textsearch ORDER BY rank DESC");

    $ids = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($items_aux); $i++) {
      $ids[$i] = $items_aux[$i]->id;
    }

    $categories = Category::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();

    $items = Item::whereIn('id', $ids)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
    $pagination = $items->appends(array(
      'adim-query' => Input::get('admin-query')
    ));

    foreach ($items as $item) {

      $img_url = Product_Image::where('id_item', '=', $item->id)->first()['url'];
      if (Storage::disk('public')->exists($img_url)) {
        $item->img = Storage::url($img_url);
      } else {
        $item->img = null;
      }
    }

    return view('pages.adminproducts', ['items' => $items, 'categories'=>$categories]);
  }
```

My Routes:

```
Route::get('admin-items/search', 'AdminItemsController@searchItems');
```

My Form:

```
<div class="form col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-4 text-center pt-0">
            <!--form-->
            <form action="/admin-items/search" method="GET" class="header-search-form" role="search">

            <input type="text" name="admin-query" id="admin-query" value="{{ request()->input('admin-query') }}" class="search-box" 
                placeholder="Search Products">
                <button><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

My Items and Links:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="management-products container-fluid card-deck justify-content-center">

                @foreach($items as $item)
                @include('partials.admin_product', $item)
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="pagination-links">
                {{ $items->links() }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Inspect the links on page loaded

```
<li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="« Previous">
<span class="page-link" aria-hidden="true">‹</span>
</li>
<li class="page-item active" aria-current="page"><span class="page-link">1</span></li>
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="http://localhost:8000/admin-items/search?adim-query=volutpat&amp;page=2">2</a></li>
 <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="http://localhost:8000/admin-items/search?adim-query=volutpat&amp;page=3">3</a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="http://localhost:8000/admin-items/search?adim-query=volutpat&amp;page=4">4</a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="http://localhost:8000/admin-items/search?adim-query=volutpat&amp;page=5">5</a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="http://localhost:8000/admin-items/search?adim-query=volutpat&amp;page=6">6</a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="http://localhost:8000/admin-items/search?adim-query=volutpat&amp;page=2" rel="next" aria-label="Next »">›</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have to make a little change inside your view. If this doesn't work then let me know, have to give you another solution**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="management-products container-fluid card-deck justify-content-center">

            @foreach($items as $item)
            @include('partials.admin_product', $item)
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="pagination-links">
            {{ $items->appends(request()->except('page'))->links() }}
            //This is important
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Or you can also do it as your code is, but with little change**

```
$items = Item::whereIn('id', $ids)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
$items = $items->appends(request()->except('page'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But, if you don't mind, could you explain why that works. It seems to me that what you added would be the same as the line 
`
 $pagination = $items->appends(array(
      'adim-query' => Input::get('admin-query')
    ));
`
and I don't understand why it isn't.

Comment: You have also used that appends method inside your controller but you haven't passed it to the view correctly. The code i have written for you is a shortcut way of doing it. This simply means that change anything in the url except the page. So it will remain on it's place.

Comment: With my code you don't need this portion of your code anymore `$pagination = $items->appends(array('adim-query' => Input::get('admin-query')));` inside your controller

Comment: Since I append it to $items and then do `return view('pages.adminproducts', ['items' => $items, 'categories'=>$categories]);` wouldn't that pass it to the view?

Comment: No you it's not passing to the view, because `$pagination` is totally a new variable and you are not passing it to view. for testing just try this code `$items = $items->appends(array('adim-query' => Input::get('admin-query')));` i am not sure about it but just give a try.

Comment: That last code doesn't work, it goes back to acting the way I described originally. But this way: `$items = $items->appends(request()->except('page'));` it works. I guess just passing the input is not enough, it needs the entire request???

Comment: Exactly you have to pass a whole request except page.